# Create and write to table in C#

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a function that return a results, here is the results:

```
3.98901669117011   vm

0.138912911874081   nvm

2.30800830234368  hg

1.13724811900026  ms

2.33557467785177   ls

90.0912392977601  none
```

I want the words to be in the top of the table, and the numbers in the rows, and in the sides some string, here is an example:

[image: Table example]

How can I create a table in C# and write to it what I wrote?

Comment: ASP.NET or WinForms? In ASP.NET you could create a DataGrid control and then return the rendered HTML string.

Comment: it's console application..
i want to create a table in a file like exel or something..

Comment: How about writing it out to a CSV file, would that work for you?

Comment: If you would explain what it is you want to do with the table you create, then we can offer some useful advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to open the exported file in Excel, you could simply save a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file. The first line would have the column names the rest of the lines would be the data rows.

The following code will write a CSV file that can be opened in Excel. It will look just like your image.

```
// I've hard coded the file contents for simplicity. 
// You'll have to generate this in your code.
string csv = 
@", nvm, hg, ms, ls, none
fun1, 12, 22, 44, 5, 77
fun2, 2, 1, 77, 45, 23
fun3, 44, 11, 12, 22, 31";

File.WriteAllText("c:\test.csv", csv);
```

Comment: i can create an xls file but how can i write to the right column\row?
i have title in the top of the table and in the side, and in the middle the information..

Comment: I've updated my example to include the first 3 columns from your image (for brevity). Each line is a row and each comma separated value is a column value in that row. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: it's not working!!
i tried this:
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\cc.csv",true);
            sw.Write("testing");

but the file stays empty.

Comment: I would use File.WriteAllText("c:\test.txt", "testing content"). Its much simpler that dealing with StreamWriter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx).

Comment: it works, but it writting to the same place, and i can't use a comma here to pass the next collumn.

Comment: If you're writing one line at a time, then you could use File.AppendAllText (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx). It may be worth while to look over the other static File methods too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file_methods.aspx

Comment: i just want to write the parameters to the right square!
how can i acces a square??

Comment: I'm assuming by square you mean table cell. I would not recommend trying to write once cell at a time. Just create one string with one row per line and then save that string to the file.

Comment: and how can i do it?
i need each parameter to be in the right cell.
how the string need to lool like, and how can i write it to the file?

Comment: I updated my example to match your image exactly. Hope this helps.